# How to get in String from String Array by Split in Java Android

Tags: java, android, json

This is my Result  where i got response from server that I want to get by Soap.I can parse this value by JSON but I'm having a problem doing so as I wish to get this value split.

```
Result=1~Saved successfully~{ "TABLE":[{ "ROW":[ { "COL":{ "UserID":"30068"}} ]}]}
```

---

I am using this code to get `UserId` values in `tmpVal`, however am not obtaining my desired results.

```
String tmpVal = returnValue.toString().split("~")[3];
```

Comment: Arrays in java are indexed from zero. You are trying to call the fourth of three elements after splitting.

Answer (score 3):

`String tmpVal = returnValue.toString().split("~")[3];`

This would give you the 4th String in the array produced by `split`, but since `split` only produced an array of 3 Strings, this code gives you an exception.

If you want to get the last part of the `split` response - `{ "TABLE":[{ "ROW":[ { "COL":{ "UserID":"30068"}} ]}]}` - you need `returnValue.toString().split("~")[2]`.

Of course, it would be safer to first test how many Strings were returned by `split` :

```
String[] splitResult = returnValue.toString().split("~");
if (splitResult.length > 2) {
    tempVal = splitResult[2];
}
```

Comment: then what will be the solution

Comment: Sorry This is not given me correct answer

Comment: This gives me { "TABLE":[{ "ROW":[ { "COL":{ "UserID":"30073"}} ]}]}

Comment: @amitsharma If you need the UserID, you have to continue spliting the result.

Comment: @amitsharma You can do, for example, `.split("\"UserID\":\"")[1]`, which will return `30068"}} ]}]}`. Then you can remove the remaining characters after the ID.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above in the comment section, Arrays start with index 0, thus if you have an array with 3 elements, the index are 0..1..2 and not 1..2..3

All you have to do is change the `String tmpVal = returnValue.toString().split("~")[3];` to:

```
String tmpVal = returnValue.toString().split("~")[2];
```

As that will obtain the 3rd element instead of the fourth element as you've been trying to do.

[You may also check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java?rq=1)